# Why does calling sqlplus from C# work on Win7(64Bit) but not on WinXP(32Bit)?

Tags: c#, sqlplus

I'm trying to get the Oracle Client version from SQL*Plus in C# and getting different results on 64-bit Windows 7 and 32-bit Windows XP.

Here's my code:

```
try
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v";
    p.Start();
    OracleClient = p.StandardOutput
        .ReadToEnd()
        .Split(':')
        .TrimStart()
        .TrimEnd('\n','\r');
    p.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    OracleClient = String.Empty;
}
```

On Windows 7, `OracleClient == "Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production"`.

On Windows XP, `OracleClient == ""`.

But when I enter the command (`sqlplus -v`) directly at the command line in XP, it works. So my question is: why does my program work on Windows 7 but not on Windows XP.

**UPDATE**

I found the error: I was reading the process' output before giving it a chance to finish.

```
try
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    OracleClient = p.StandardOutput
        .ReadToEnd()
        .Split(':')
        .TrimStart()
        .TrimEnd('\n','\r');
}
catch (Exception)
{
    OracleClient = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not an environment problem (path, ...)

Comment: Well I think not but I try it

Comment: Have you tried printing out the everything in `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`? You access index 1 of the result of `Split`. Maybe the `Split` doesn't return the same array on both platforms.

Comment: I comment Split out and tried it but it doesnt work. I think the Problem is the different between the 64Bit Windows7 and the 32 Bit Windows XP. But i have no idea why

Comment: Check if StandardError has some information.